# How do I interpret the identification step logs in Causal Inference using DoWhy?

Tags: causality, causal-diagram, causalimpact

I am running Causal Inference to determine whether the mass of a vehicle affects the Co2 emissions. I understand that DoWhy follows a particular structure that is modeling-> identification -> estimation -> refutations. I was logging the outputs of each step in Python. I am having trouble understanding and interpreting the results of the Identification step in the code I am running. This is the specific log I am having trouble with:

[image: Snippet of my print statements when running the identification step]

How should I approach reading this output? And what information is it telling me?

Comment: I don't think the edit adds much to the original post. The question is how to interpret the assumption 1. The assumption 1 is that the analysis has no confounding. The real question is whether you understand confounding.